# Cannot Build Docker Image For Angular 9 Application

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile

I have a reasonably complex Angular 9 application that uses third party solutions like leaflet, threejs, and PrimeNG components.  I cannot build a Docker image with my Dockerfile.

I can build most of the simple apps that people have published regarding Docker<->Angular.  But these apps do little more than 'Hello World' or show an Angular logo.

Note that I can build project fine in Visual Studio Code.  I show a picture of Angular 9 project at the bottom.  Using a Dockerfile from one of the simple videos, I made a few modifications for naming reasons.  I use node:12.2.0 since that is what I am using in VSC.

```
# stage 1 get any base dockerhub images
FROM node:12.2.0 AS builder

# here I build a base working directory "inside the image!" as /app
WORKDIR /app

# this copy will copy all files from the Frontend_Serenity_A9 folder to the /app directory in the image.
COPY . .

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod

#STAGE 2
FROM nginx:1.15.8-alpine
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/Frontend_Serenity_A9 /usr/share/nginx/html
```

When it tries build the Docker image, it takes about 6 minutes and then fails.  I show the salient parts of the build process and then failure below.  Note that it also says to look at the log files for more detail, but I cannot find those log files anywhere on my machine.

Have been working on this for a week and trying everything.  Any help or ideas you have are GREATLY appreciated.  Thanks!!

```
> Executing task: docker build --pull --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t frontendserenitya9:test1 "." <

[+] Building 345.3s (10/12)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                          0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 465B                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                 0.1s 
 => => transferring context: 52B                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:1.15.8-alpine                                                                                                                                            1.3s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:12.2.0                                                                                                                                                    1.0s 
 => [builder 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/node:12.2.0@sha256:3d4411d1933dc93e78b9e0de556a22178269952b98cbbea7ca935d890527ae27                                                                                      0.0s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                 0.7s 
 => => transferring context: 56.61MB                                                                                                                                                                              0.7s 
 => CACHED [stage-1 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:1.15.8-alpine@sha256:e0292d158b6b353fde34909243a4886977cb9d1abb8a8a5fef9e0ff7138dd3e2                                                                       0.0s 
 => CACHED [builder 2/5] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s 
 => [builder 3/5] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                                                        0.2s 
 => [builder 4/5] RUN npm install                                                                                                                                                                               107.7s 
 => [builder 5/5] RUN npm run build --prod                                                                                                                                                                       25.2s 
 => => # Compiling @angular/forms : es2015 as esm2015
 => => # Compiling @angular/common/http : es2015 as esm2015
 => => # Compiling @angular/animations : es2015 as esm2015
 => => # Compiling @angular/animations/browser : es2015 as esm2015
 => => # Compiling @angular/platform-browser/animations : es2015 as esm2015                                                                                                                                            
 => => # Compiling @angular/cdk/platform : es2015 as esm2015                   <<<  Stays on this for a few minutes

#11 6.689 Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
#11 11.18 Compiling @angular/common : es2015 as esm2015
#11 12.36 Compiling @angular/platform-browser : es2015 as esm2015
#11 13.77 Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : es2015 as esm2015
#11 16.49 Compiling @angular/forms : es2015 as esm2015
#11 18.64 Compiling @angular/common/http : es2015 as esm2015
...
...
#11 55.01 Compiling primeng/api : es2015 as esm2015
#11 55.95 Compiling primeng/accordion : es2015 as esm2015
#11 57.79 Compiling primeng/inputtext : es2015 as esm2015
#11 58.26 Compiling primeng/dom : es2015 as esm2015
#11 59.12 Compiling primeng/button : es2015 as esm2015
#11 59.84 Compiling primeng/utils : es2015 as esm2015
#11 216.0 Compiling primeng : es2015 as esm2015
#11 244.6 Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
#11 534.7 An unhandled exception occurred: Call retries were exceeded
#11 534.7 See "/tmp/ng-lcHnam/angular-errors.log" for further details.
#11 534.7 npm ERR! file sh
#11 534.7 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
#11 534.7 npm ERR! errno ENOENT
#11 534.7 npm ERR! syscall spawn
#11 534.7 npm ERR! serenity@9.0.0 build: `ng build`
#11 534.7 npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
#11 534.7 npm ERR!
#11 534.7 npm ERR! Failed at the serenity@9.0.0 build script.
#11 534.7 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
#11 534.7
#11 534.7 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#11 534.7 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-11-27T10_25_28_611Z-debug.log
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm run build --prod]: runc did not terminate sucessfully
```

[image]

Adding package.json contents here (edit #1).

```
{
  "name": "serenity",
  "version": "9.0.0",
  "license": "PrimeNG Commercial",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "9.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "9.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "9.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "9.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "9.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "9.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "9.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "9.0.4",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "4.0.2",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "4.0.1",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "4.0.2",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "4.0.1",
    "@handsontable/angular": "^5.1.1",
    "@mdi/svg": "^5.3.45",
    "@types/leaflet-draw": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/plotly.js": "^1.50.12",
    "chart.js": "2.7.3",
    "d3": "^5.16.0",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "handsontable": "^7.4.2",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
    "leaflet-draw": "^1.0.4",
    "leaflet-sidebar-v2": "^3.2.2",
    "leaflet.control.layers.tree": "^1.0.0",
    "leaflet.glify": "^3.0.0",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "plotly.js-dist": "^1.54.1",
    "primeflex": "1.0.0",
    "primeng": "9.0.1",
    "prismjs": "1.15.0",
    "quill": "1.1.8",
    "rxjs": "6.5.4",
    "three": "^0.117.1",
    "web-animations-js": "github:angular/web-animations-js#release_pr208",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.2",
    "zone.js": "0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.900.4",
    "@angular/cli": "9.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "9.0.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "9.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.5.7",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.5.17",
    "@types/node": "12.12.29",
    "codelyzer": "5.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.5.2",
    "protractor": "5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "8.3.0",
    "tslint": "5.18.0",
    "typescript": "3.7.5"
  }
}
```

The errors it is reporting in angular-errors.log are:

```
[error] Error: Call retries were exceeded
    at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (c:\development\gems\Frontend_Serenity_A9_SLIM\Frontend_Serenity_A9\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:193:21)
    at ChildProcessWorker.onExit (c:\development\gems\Frontend_Serenity_A9_SLIM\Frontend_Serenity_A9\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:263:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
```

I don't even need the docker process (Update), it does this just during an "ng build" command.  I have increased the memory size of node as well.  Still no luck.

Comment: What version of `primeng` are you using in your package.json? Are you building the docker image locally of via some kind of CI pipeline?

Comment: Thanks @JohnGraham for responding.  primeng in my package.json is:    "primeng": "9.0.1".  I am building the docker image locally on my laptop.  I try both from Visual Studio Code (Command Palette) and a DOS window with the same results.  Thanks again.  I added the contents of my package.json above.

Comment: You might want to try to go back to es5 as your target in tsconfig.app.json (from es2015). This disabled differential loading and helped with similar problems in other projects for us.